# Change parameter of long running awaitable task

Tags: c#, async-await

I have a long running async method that does a calculation based on parameters that I pass to this method.

It looks a bit like this:

```
public async Task<Measurement> StartMeasurementAsync(
                                int duration, 
                                int nbr, 
                                double parameter,
                                IProgress<IntermediateResults> progress,
                                CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
   Measurement measurement = new Measurement { Parameter = parameter };

   for(int i = 0; i < nbr; i++)
   {
       var rawData = await RunMeasurement(duration, progress, cancellationToken);

       var treatedData = DataTreatment.Treat(rawData, parameter);
       measurement.Data.Add(treatedData);

       cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
   }

   return measurement;
}
```

Basically this method is called in my UI, I'm using the progress to refresh a visual representation of my raw data, for which the user can change a parameter. This parameter is the same as the one passed at the method.

The data treatement called after the await in the for loop is also called in the UI, so that the user can see "live" the result changing this parameter would make on the raw data. But then, I need to tell the long-running task that the parameter has changed, so that it would be saved correctly in the `Measurement`.

That's where I'm stuck, how can I tell the task that this parameter has changed?

Comment: Interpreting what you are asking literally you could pass a `ref` param, but altering ref params from another thread is asking for data corruption. I think you should just cancel the existing task and start a new one with the new parameter.

Comment: If you call an async method to do a calculation based on a parameter, and that parameter can change during calculation, shouldn't you restart the calculation?

Comment: @BenRobinson AFAIK you can't use `ref` with `async` method to start with.

Comment: I don't need (nor want) to cancel the whole thing because this parameter is shared between all my "Data" and it's OK to recalculate this Data if it does change. The parameter is saved at the `Measurement` level, but I don't have the reference to the currently-running `Measurement` to update from the UI.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Probably a good that you can't do it then ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be compared to the downloading a web page asynchronously say using `HttpClient`.

Let's say you've initiated some web request. After a while user is not interested in the requested page for some reason and interested in some other page, you'll typically cancel the request and start new request.

You can't say that *Hey now I'm interested in new page after the operation has started and going half the way. You must cancel it and start new one*.

Same logic applies here. You'll have to cancel the asynchronous operation and start the new one. It seems you already support cancellation in your long running method. So I guess it isn't a big deal to cancel the previous operation and start new one.

Alternatively you can pass a mutable object as a parameter to `StartMeasurementAsync` and mutate it when you need to change it(with proper synchronization). Then poll for the change, or implement some kind of change notification (say `INotifyPropertyChanged`) and act accordingly in your asynchronous method.

IMO first method is cleaner, My vote is for cancelling and restarting the operation.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't cancel the operation. I need to save the intermediate results and keep them, even if the user cancels the operation. Changing this parameter doesn't change the whole logic as changing the URI of a web request would, it's just a minor parameter used for some calculation.

Comment: Does alternate way described in my answer helps? Or..? I'm not certain about what your code does and how that depends on the parameter passed in. So I can't provide code help:(

Comment: I've tried passing a mutable object, but I seem to hit some concurrency issues. Can you give me some clue about the "proper synchronization"?

Comment: @Gimly You should be using locks around accessing that mutable object. It is tricky, if you can provide some sample code explaining how you intend to use it, I'll try to help. Take a look at [this](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part2.aspx#_Locking)

Comment: Actually, I found a better solution, I'm passing that parameter and doing the calculation after the task has finished. It makes much more sense in the end and I don't risk any concurrency issue. So my question is kind of null.